# Different way to scrape asin on Amazon webpage with Python and Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

Actually, I scrape asin on amazon webpage with this code:

```
asin = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "averageCustomerReviews"))).get_attribute("data-asin")
```

But i have a problem: when the product has not customer reviews, i get an error with this code: `timeout, asin not found`. I want to scrape asin on this part of page source code, for example:

https://www.amazon.fr/dp/B08HNBD7XX

[image]

Anyone know how to make for to scrape asin on this part of source code please?

Comment: If you used xpath you can use | to check for multiple different values in css selector  its , so just grab that value by its td class and you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks for answer @Armande Chohan, you know how to build this code please?

Answer (score 1):

Wrap up your code block in a `try-except{}` inducing [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the [*visibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50468629/python-selenium-wait-until-element-is-fully-loaded/50474905#50474905) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

```
try:
    asin = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "averageCustomerReviews"))).get_attribute("data-asin")
    print("data-asin attribute was found")
    continue
except TimeoutException:
    print("data-asin attribute wasn't found")
    continue
```

Comment: Hello and thank you for your answer @DebanjanB.  Unfortunately with your code, if I can't find asin, my code crashes.  I absolutely have to get asin in this part of the source code, because it is present on every article page.

Comment: @JohnDoe The code within this answer is just an improvemt to the logic which you wanted to implement. I don't see any element as `(By.ID, "averageCustomerReviews")` in the snapshot either.

Comment: try-except is already in place in my code. But i just want to know how to make for scrap asin in source code on snapshot.
I've tested:
```
asin_n = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "(//td[@class='.prodDetAttrValue'])"))).text
```
But not work